# Pandas getting nsmallest avg for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of values and I'm trying to curvefit a lower bound based on avg of the nsmallest values.

The dataframe is organized with theline data (y-vals) in each row, and the columns are ints from 0 to end (x-vals) and I need to return the nsmallest y-vals for each x value ideally to avg out and return as a series if possible with xy-vals.

DataFrame nsmallest() doesn't return nsmallest in each column individually which is what I want/need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where `apply` works for small amount of columns:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(n=5).to_numpy())
```